# Restrict number of jobs by a rule in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to restrict number of jobs to run by a particular rule in snakemake? `--jobs` controls globably how many jobs are allowed to run at a time, but I would like to restrict by a specific rule.

This is because, I have a particular rule that can be used at most for two jobs in parallel. However, if I set `--jobs` to 20, this results in tool in that particular rule crashing. I use snakemake v5.2.0 in LSF cluster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could probably use resources.

Define them in a rule

```
rule only_two:
    ...
    resources:
        load=50
    ...
```

and then run `snakemake` with a certain resource limit.

```
snakemake --resources load=100
```

It should only run two instances of rule `only_two`.

All other rules might have a `load` value of 1 or less and you could run 100 or more of them simultaneously.

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources

Comment: This worked, but could you link me to doc for `load` option? I couldn't find it on my search.

Comment: Never mind. Just learnt that `load` here is an arbitrary term.